# Change position of submit button on form

Tags: 6, forms

This is my code:

```
function feature_contact_form_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)
{ 
if ($form_id == 'contact_form_node_form') {
  $form['field_user_agent']['#type'] = 'hidden';
  $form['field_ip_address']['#type']      = 'hidden';
  $form['buttons']['submit']['#weight'] = -15;
}
}
```

I am using Drupal 6. I am trying to change the position of the submit button. I am using conditional fields also on this content type. weighting is not changing the position.

Comment: Did you try with `$form['buttons']['#weight'] = -15;`?

Comment: that didn't work.

Comment: is your module named `feature_contact_form` ?  if not, this code is probably not be being called at all as the form alter hook should be MODULENAME_form_alter(...).  Try that and @kiamlaluno's suggestion and see what happens.

Comment: Are you using custom module? If you didn't used any custom module try this in template.php file mytheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)

Comment: The function is definitely being called because the field_user_agent field is being hidden correctly

Comment: I am using a custom module. Why would this code need to go in template.php instead?

Comment: I am going to try the code in the template file.

Comment: the reason it wasn't working on my side was a bug on my dev site. On the production site it works.

Comment: I am using a panel layout on node add/edit and this seems to be causing the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the form elements submit buttons onto the node add/edit panel in the correct place, which solved my problem.